# Gson not deserialising ArrayList as expected

Tags: java, json, gson

This is my Json string:

```
jsonString ="{"Extras":[{"Name":"TEST","Value":"23455676654"}],"CommandCode":1005}"
```

This is my Class

```
public class ServerMsg {  
    int CommandCode;  
    public List<Extra> extras = new ArrayList<Extra>();  
}
```

When I code:

```
ServerMsg msg = new ServerMsg();  
Gson gSon = new Gson();
msg = gSon.fromJson(jsonString,Servermsg.class);
```

I get no objects in the extras list.
What have I coded incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your JSON object with name `Extras` to `extras`

```
{"extras":[{"Name":"TEST","Value":"23455676654"}],"CommandCode":1005}
```

Or change the field name from `extras` to `Extras`.

```
public class ServerMsg {  
    int CommandCode;  
    public List<Extra> Extras = new ArrayList<Extra>();  
}
```

Gson, by default, uses your field names. They have to match the nested JSON object names.

You should use Java naming conventions and write your variable names with a leading lowercase character.